# Loading indicator is not shown in header in angular

Tags: html, angular

During service calls, I have given loading indicator, but it is not preventing the user to tap on header items. I want to prevent the user to do any action on the page until the the loading indicator stops.

Comment: added answer have look, it will good if you provide some code

Answer (score 0):

Add a class on a header.

```
.disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

<div [hidden]="loading" class="loading-indicator">
    <loading-indicator></loading-indicator>
</div>

 <app-header [ngClass]="{'disabled' : !loading}"></app-header>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it is working for buttons and images in header but I have a dropdown  for that still I am able to click

Answer (score 0):

try like this by making use of `*ngIf ...else`

```
<app-header *ngIf="!loading;else loading_content">
    content here ...
</app-header>

<ng-template #loading_content>Loading content...</ng-template>
```